# Why is this function not a group isomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I have defined a homorphism $\phi: Z/100Z * Z/10Z  \rightarrow Z/1000Z$ defined as $\phi ((a,b)) \rightarrow a*10 + b$ and from what I can tell this is a valid isomorphism. Can someone explain to me why my function is not an isomorphism?

edit: reworded to show uniqueness of question

Comment: whatever it is it is not an isomorphism. Either the condition $\phi(u+v)=\phi(u)+\phi(v)$ fails, or $\phi$ is not surjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\phi\big((0,5)\big) &= 5,
\\
(0,5)+(0,5) = (0,5+5)&=(0,0),\qquad\text{the second coordinate computed in }Z/10Z
\\
\phi\big((0,5)+(0,5)\big) = \phi\big((0,0)\big) &= 0 \ne 10 = 5+5
\qquad\text{the $5+5$ computed in }Z/1000Z
\end{align}

Comment: This makes perfect sense to me! thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one reason (among many, but you only need one) why your function is not an isomorphism.

In $\mathbb Z / 1000 \mathbb Z$ we have $\phi(100,10) = 100*10 + 10 = 1010 = 10$ modulo $1000$.

But $100 = 0$ mod $100$, and $10 = 0$ mod $10$, so $\phi(100) * \phi(10) = \phi(0) * \phi(0) = 0$ mod $1000$.

And $10 \ne 0$ modulo $1000$.